# mootools Fx.slide not working IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, mootools

I have some javascript that is built on top of mootools that is basically giving a div some show/hide functionality.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
/*var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('customise_text').hide()
var mySlide2 = new Fx.Slide('customise_link').hide()
$('customise').addEvent('click', function(e){
    $('customise').addClass('active');
    mySlide.toggle(); //show-hide login panel
    mySlide2.toggle(); //show-hide login panel
    e.preventDefault();
});*/

/*$('moodal_close').addEvent('click', function(){
    alert("1");
});*/
//alert("hello")
var vertical_slide = $('vertical_slide');
var checkoutVerticalSlide = $('vertical_slide_checkout');
var v_toggle_checkout = $('v_toggle_checkout');

if(!vertical_slide || !checkoutVerticalSlide || !v_toggle_checkout) {
    return;
} else {

    var status = {
        'true': 'open',
        'false': 'close'
    };
    //-vertical
    var myVerticalSlide = new Fx.Slide('vertical_slide').hide();
    $('v_toggle').addEvent('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        myVerticalSlide.toggle();
    });

    // When Vertical Slide ends its transition, we check for its status
    // note that complete will not affect 'hide' and 'show' methods
    myVerticalSlide.addEvent('complete', function() {
        if(status[myVerticalSlide.open] == 'open')
        {
            $('v_toggle').addClass('open');
        } else {
            $('v_toggle').removeClass('open');
        }
    });

    var checkout_status = {
        'true': 'open',
        'false': 'close'
    };

    var checkoutVerticalSlide = new Fx.Slide('vertical_slide_checkout').hide();
    $('v_toggle_checkout').addEvent('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        checkoutVerticalSlide.toggle();
    });

    checkoutVerticalSlide.addEvent('complete', function() {
        if(status[checkoutVerticalSlide.open] == 'open')
        {
            $('v_toggle_checkout').addClass('open');
        } else {
            $('v_toggle_checkout').removeClass('open');
        }
    });
}
```

In IE6 I get page loaded with errors and get an error of `Object does not support this method or property`

Comment: Do you know what is causing the error? IE6 is a pain to track this down - about your only option is sprinkling alerts() to see how the code progresses, and where it fails.  I would recommend at the start and end of each function, to narrow it down.  alert('Starting complete event'); alert('ending complete event'); etc.  Then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to the fact that IE6 does not support the preventDefault method.

Where you make use of this method (e.preventDefault()), replace the call with the following

```
if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } else { e.returnValue = false; }
```

See if that works for you :)

While it feels warm and fuzzy to be able to support all browsers, IE6 is not a warm and fuzzy kind of browser. You will keep running into problems if you want to fully support IE6, I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 to "You will keep running into problems if you want to fully support IE6, I'm afraid"

Comment: I don't unfortunatly this functionality while it shouldnt be as it is powered by javascript is integrel to the site

Comment: Fair enough - in most cases you should be able to work around these problems, layouts can be a headache sometimes thought. All the best!